# Why can't I write on External Hard disk?

Tags: arch-linux, hard-disk

I am using Arch Linux. I am not able to write on my external hard disk. I have tried to change the permission manually through properties but not allowed to do so. How can I fix this problem?

Here is the output of `fsck -l` and `mount`:

```
[root@localhost shravan]# fsck -l
fsck from util-linux 2.24.1
e2fsck 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
/dev/sda1 is mounted.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.


[root@localhost shravan]# mount
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sys on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
dev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=1996364k,nr_inodes=499091,mode=755)
run on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,mode=755)
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=22,pgrp=1,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=399844k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
/dev/sdb1 on /run/media/shravan/6FA6C3EC7A96B1D0 type ntfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0177,dmask=077,nls=utf8,errors=continue,mft_zone_multiplier=1,uhelper=udisks2)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
```

Comment: Is the external hard disk formatted correctly? Are you able to mount the external HDD?

Comment: Yes, it is formated correctly and able to mount it.

Comment: How you are trying to write to the external disk?

Comment: Like copying some data from internal hard disk. Even i can't create a new folder.

Comment: Ok, what is the output of `fsck -l` and `mount` commands?

Comment: Here is the output of both commands : http://pastie.org/9225854

Comment: The above output was observed, When i was not root. Here is the ouptput as root user : http://pastie.org/9225866

Comment: Please see the answer and let me know if that is fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I observe in the output of the pastebin page, I see the external HDD is formatted as NTFS partition.

```
/dev/sdb1 on /run/media/shravan/6FA6C3EC7A96B1D0 type ntfs 
(ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0177,dmask=077,nls=utf8,
errors=continue,mft_zone_multiplier=1,uhelper=udisks2)
```

So I believe if you remount your partition as NTFS type you will be able to use the external HDD. Just unmount your partition using `umount /dev/sdb1` and then remount it using the below command.

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /run/media/shravan/ -t ntfs-3g -o nls=utf8,umask=0222
```

As per Patrick's comments, the file system is mounted with the in-kernel ntfs driver, which is read only. So if the system has `ntfs-3g` the `mount` should be used as,

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /run/media/shravan/ -t ntfs-3g -o nls=utf8,umask=0222
```

**References**

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/mounting-a-windows-xp-ntfs-partition-in-linux/
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/conversation/ntfs-3g-use
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/conversation/mikeserv-suggestion

Comment: Note:  Windows 10 may not unmount a drive properly even when shutdown (some new fast boot functionality) so Linux will only mount it read-only.