# Permission denied on mounted devices

Tags: debian, permissions, mount, ntfs

I have checked many similar questions but the solutions didn't work for me.
On my previous Debian wheezy installation I could mount devices from GUI with no permission problem and also after upgrading to jessie. But on my new Debian jessie installation devices mount in a read-only state whether ntfs partitions on the same HDD as my Debian installation or external USB devices, for both root user and normal user, I can't write and modify data on mounted devices.

I have found these lines in syslog that seems to be related.

```
udisksd[1281]: Mounted /dev/sda4 at /media/<user>/<uuid> on behalf of uid 1000
udisksd[1281]: Cleaning up mount point /media/<user>/<uuid> (device 8:4 is not mounted)
udisksd[1281]: Unmounted /dev/sda4 on behalf of uid 1000
kernel: [  125.190099] ntfs: volume version 3.1.
udisksd[1281]: Mounted /dev/sda4 at /media/<user>/<uuid> on behalf of uid 1000
org.gtk.Private.UDisks2VolumeMonitor[1224]: index_parse.c:191: indx_parse(): error opening /media/<user>/<uuid>/BDMV/index.bdmv
org.gtk.Private.UDisks2VolumeMonitor[1224]: index_parse.c:191: indx_parse(): error opening /media/<user>/<uuid>/BDMV/BACKUP/index.bdmv
org.gnome.Nautilus[1224]: Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
kernel: [  137.739543] ntfs: (device sda4): ntfs_setattr(): Changes in user/group/mode are not supported yet, ignoring.
kernel: [  137.739579] ntfs: (device sda4): ntfs_setattr(): Changes in user/group/mode are not supported yet, ignoring.
kernel: [  137.739655] ntfs: (device sda4): ntfs_setattr(): Changes in user/group/mode are not supported yet, ignoring.
kernel: [  137.739678] ntfs: (device sda4): ntfs_setattr(): Changes in user/group/mode are not supported yet, ignoring.
kernel: [  137.739702] ntfs: (device sda4): ntfs_setattr(): Changes in user/group/mode are not supported yet, ignoring.
kernel: [  137.739767] ntfs: (device sda4): ntfs_setattr(): Changes in user/group/mode are not supported yet, ignoring.
kernel: [  137.739791] ntfs: (device sda4): ntfs_setattr(): Changes in user/group/mode are not supported yet, ignoring.
kernel: [  137.739814] ntfs: (device sda4): ntfs_setattr(): Changes in user/group/mode are not supported yet, ignoring.
kernel: [  137.739894] ntfs: (device sda4): ntfs_setattr(): Changes in user/group/mode are not supported yet, ignoring.
kernel: [  137.739921] ntfs: (device sda4): ntfs_setattr(): Changes in user/group/mode are not supported yet, ignoring.
```

I'm trying to figure out what makes the difference between two installations. In my new installation, unlike the previous one, I didn't install gnome task completely but only the minimal gnome packages. And the other difference is that the first time I created a fresh partition table and formatted all the partitions, ext4 and ntfs, then installed windows and then Debian, but second time I used the same partition table and only formatted ext4 partitions. Both times dual-boot with windows.

The output of `cat /etc/mtab` for two internal and external mounted devices reads as follows:

```
/dev/sdb1 /media/<user>/<uuid> ntfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0177,dmask=077,nls=utf8,errors=continue,mft_zone_multiplier=1 0 0
/dev/sda4 /media/<user>/<uuid> ntfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0177,dmask=077,nls=utf8,errors=continue,mft_zone_multiplier=1 0 0
```

Comment: I had to set `uid`. `mount -o uid=1000 /dev/sdaX /mnt`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After hours searching, there seems to be different causes for this issue and different solutions for each one.

I'm not an expert to provide a comprehensive answer so I hint to some frequent situations on the topic:

- Ownership/permission issues for mounted devices on mount points:
  [File permissions won't change](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342791/file-permissions-wont-change)
  [USB drive auto-mounted by user but gets write permissions for root only](https://askubuntu.com/questions/405993/usb-drive-auto-mounted-by-user-but-gets-write-permissions-for-root-only)
- Damaged file-system that for security reasons mounts the device as read-only:
  [Permission Denied on External Hard Drive](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1373614&page=2&p=8623065#post8623065)
- Hibernated windows that doesn't permit a write access to windows partitions on dual-boot systems:
  [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)
- And the one that led me to answer is the type of mounting based on the file-system:
  [Why can't I write on External Hard disk?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132273/why-cant-i-write-on-external-hard-disk)

My problem was the missing NTFS driver package `ntfs-3g` that caused the system use the Linux kernel NTFS driver `ntfs`. As mentioned in [Debian Wiki NTFS](https://wiki.debian.org/NTFS) page, `ntfs`, Linux kernel NTFS driver, provides read-only access, and `ntfs-3g`, Userspace NTFS driver via FUSE, provides read and write access.

`# apt-get install ntfs-3g` and a system reboot solved the problem for me.

Comment: ntfs-3g was the answer for me

Comment: ntfs-3g was the answer for me, too.

Answer (score 1):

I was having "permission denied" errors while trying to read the contents of some files on an NTFS partition - even as root.  There were no permissions problems with the folder tree (checked with `namei -l $PWD`).

`/var/log/syslog` was showing an error in ntfs-3g every time I failed to read the contents of a file:

```
Jun 20 21:27:23 matthew-pc ntfs-3g[5653]: ntfs_attr_pread error reading '/Users/Matthew/Documents/test.txt' at offset 0: 566 <> -1: Permission denied
```

After reading https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ntfs-3g/+bug/307289, I realised the problem files were encrypted, which naturally prevented me from reading them, but the error itself didn't help me very much.