# udisks2 - acl can't get write permissions for a regular user

Tags: linux, permissions, acl, udisks

External storage devices are successfully mounted to /run/media/myuser/ via `udisks2` (`udisksd` service`). I can read data from devices. However I can NOT write to them. I'm trying to edit directory ACLs in order to get write permissions for regular`myuser` I'm logged in with (not root)

Default permissions are as follows:

```
getfacl /run/media                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names                                                                                                                                                                                        
# file: run/media
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
mask::r-x
other::r-x


getfacl /run/media/myuser                                                                                                                                                                                                            
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names                                                                                                                                                                                       # file: run/media/myuser
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::---
mask::---
other::---


getfacl /run/media/myuser/mydisk                                                                                                                                                                                  
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names                                                                                                                                                                                        
# file: run/media/myuser/mydisk
# owner: myuser                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
# group: myuser                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
user::rwx
group::---
other::---
```

The above default setup prevents me from writing data to mounted device `/run/media/mydisk`.  I tried to add write acl permission to myuser for /run/media/myuser dirrectory.

```
getfacl /run/media/myuser                                                                                                                                                                                                            
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names                                                                                                                                                                                        
# file: run/media/myuser
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:myuser:rwx
group::---
mask::rwx
other::---
```

However that did not change anything.
Please note that I'm not able to write any data to the mounted device even with sudo elevated `myuser`.
Please, how can I solve the issue so I can write data to the mounted devices?

Linux myuser 4.11.9-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jul 5 18:23:08 CEST 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
systemctl status udisks2                         
● udisks2.service - Disk Manager                           
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/udisks2.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2017-07-18 01:32:51 CEST; 11min ago                                              
     Docs: man:udisks(8)                                   
 Main PID: 549 (udisksd)                                   
    Tasks: 5 (limit: 4915)                                 
   CGroup: /system.slice/udisks2.service                   
           └─549 /usr/lib/udisks2/udisksd

Jul 18 01:32:51 myuser systemd[1]: Starting Disk Manager...
Jul 18 01:32:51 myuser udisksd[549]: udisks daemon version 2.7.0 starting
Jul 18 01:32:51 myuser udisksd[549]: Acquired the name org.freedesktop.UDisks2 on the system message bus
Jul 18 01:32:51 myuser systemd[1]: Started Disk Manager.   
Jul 18 01:32:52 myuser udisksd[549]: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed
Jul 18 01:32:52 myuser udisksd[549]: Mounted /dev/sdd1 at /run/media/myuser/mydisk on behalf of uid 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently default in-kernel `ntfs` driver mount devices in read-only mode.
More information [HERE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132273/why-cant-i-write-on-external-hard-disk)

Solution:

> sudo pacman -S ntfs-3g